Window Rating Question
I'm facing a hurricane and hoping to gain understanding on what my windows are capable of withstanding. There is a label but I have no idea what it means and Google gives mixed results.
Label says
AAMA
Test: NCTL-210-2319-1
Spec: DH-R30/R45/R55
REIN: None
Forced entry resistant.

Are you quite sure that's DH and not DP? [Edit] in a picture of the label.

Yes, I double checked. My googling tells me the DH is “double hung”

According to a bit of web-searching, see https://floridabuilding.org/upload/PR_Tech_Docs/FL14022_R2_AE_NCTL%20210-3580-1%20HVHZ.pdf NCTL stands for "National Certified Testing Laboratories". "210-2319-1" may be the report number for the window's test by NCTL. The linked PDF has NCTL's phone number. You might call them to see if they can send you that report. You might do better putting plywood on the windows instead of hoping the glass will withstand the wind & impacts. Be safe, and please evacuate if they tell you to!
